# I would like excel to highlight a cell based on vlookup if then statement

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I deal with contract changes every month. Each month I have to account for the money changes that happen with those contracts. I keep a running spreadsheet of each time I make a change that will change the price. I run a monthly report that the shows money changes. I compare to what I know I did to what the system shows happening.  The monthly report is not always correct because the changes I did don't always show. I make adjustments at the bottom of my sheet. Each month I have to account for the previous month's adjustments so I don't account for a money change twice. I have unique contract numbers that I can vlookup to see if the change shows up the next month. When that changes shows up I want the cell highlighted to show me I've already accounted for that money. After I've highlighted everything that I already know I have accounted for then I can search my sheet for other money changes that haven't been accounted for to find out why they changed. I've read several posts about conditional formatting and none seem to match what I need it to do. The contract numbers change every month. It seems to me setting up the conditional formula for each contract number would take more time than just ctrl F and highlighting it myself. Or maybe I'm not understanding conditional formatting and there is a way?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option I know of is the following:

- Select the colum that contains the contract numbers
- At the home tab (in the ribbon) choose conditional formatting->highlight cell rules->duplicate values.

This way all values that occur twice will be highlighted, making it easier for you to identify these values. Alternatively, you could:

- Again select the column that contains the contract numbers
- At the home tab (in the ribbon) choose conditional formatting->new rule->use a formula to determine which cells to format
- then, at **Format values where the formula is true**, fill in "=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)>1".
- Click format->fill and choose a color. 
  Now excel will automatically format the first of the duplicate values in red, and the consecutive ones in the color you selected.